# How to implement raw_input without echo in python in Windows?

Tags: python-2.7

I need this to authorize on a child process. getpass cannot be used because both getch and putch need will not work without a windows console (the child process is created but there is no visible console). Is there a way where I can remove the echo for raw_input?

The no-echo part is important because I log all the input on child process to a file and I don't want anyone to see the passwords

Comment: I don't understand the limitations you have. If you don't have a console, `raw_input` has nowhere to echo to (nor read from). Do you want to do keyboard capturing somehow, with no (visible) GUI, or are you asking for something else?

Comment: Yeah, my bad, sorry. I don't have a visible console and I don't want to capture the keyboard strokes. I have script where I spawn a process. It is this process that requires authorization. getch and putch using msvcrt on Windows work only on a console. So, I was wondering if I can use raw_input without echo.